# What does ‘readystatechange’ event for ‘window’ mean?

Tags: javascript, window, microsoft-edge, readystate, onreadystatechange

Trying to handle `window.onreadystatechange`, I notice this event firing **two times** during page load. But I cannot figure out what exactly becomes changed after each event. If it were not for `window`, but for `document`, then there had been `document.readyState` property containing the current state. But in case of `window`, there isn’t any `“window.readyState”` or similar property. So what does it really mean when a `readystatechange` event for `window` fires, and what the difference between the first and the second firing is?

Here is my code that gives two seemingly identical console outputs:

```js
'use strict';

window.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(e) {
  console.log(window, e);
});
```

Comment: "readyState" is indeed a property on the document object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState

Comment: I don't get any events. What browser are you using? What other scripts are loaded on that page?

Comment: @JeffMcCloud, I know a lot about `readyState` property and `readystatechange` event for `document`, but my question was about handling this event for `window`, not for `document`.

Comment: @Bergi, I’m using MS Edge 38.14393.0.0, and since it’s a test page, no other scripts are linked to the page.

Comment: Is it possible Edge somehow makes it bubble to the window ? Can you check if it corresponds to the document events ?

Comment: @Displayname Ah, cannot reproduce in another browser. Can you post which values you get for `e`?

Comment: @Bergi, here it goes: {
   [functions]: ,
   __proto__: { },
   AT_TARGET: 2,
   bubbles: true,
   BUBBLING_PHASE: 3,
   cancelable: false,
   cancelBubble: false,
   CAPTURING_PHASE: 1,
   currentTarget: { },
   defaultPrevented: false,
   eventPhase: 3,
   isTrusted: true,
   returnValue: true,
   srcElement: { },
   target: { },
   timeStamp: 1481592095815,
   type: "readystatechange"
}

Comment: Interesting. I'll guess that `__proto__` is `Event.prototype` and `currentTarget` is `window`. But what are `target` and `srcElement`, do they refer to `document`?

Comment: Yes @Bergi, you’re right. `target` and `srcElement` both refer to `document`, while `currentTarget` is `window`.

Comment: And `bubbles` is `true`, which confirms @Kaiido's theory. Although it [shouldn't](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange). And really not from `document` to `window`. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`window` only fires the `readystatechange` event in IE and Edge (tested in IE 11).
It does NOT fire in Firefox or Chrome.

It is actually fired by the document, when its `readyState` changes to `"interactive"` and `"complete"` (bubbling).

Thus, in IE:

```
window.onreadystatechange == document.onreadystatechange
```

I would not recommend using it though, as this event is not fired in the other browsers.

Comment: It's compatible with other browsers! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readystatechange_event#Browser_compatibility